# Eliminar todos los elementos de un treeMap

Tags: java, map

Quisiera saber como eliminar todos los elementos de una lista `treeMap` de Java.
Tengo el método siguiente que me elimina solamente un elemento:

```
public boolean eliminarProducte(String codi){
     return map_catalogo.remove(codi)!=null;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como todas las demás colecciones de Java, si quieres eliminar todos los elementos, simplemente llamas al método [`clear()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#clear--).

```
map_catalogo.clear();
```

Comment: Otra forma igual efectiva es re instanciar el mapa (si es posible).

Answer (score 4):

Debes usar el método [clear()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/treemap_clear.htm) que elimina todas las asignaciones de este `TreeMap`.

Ejemplo:

```
  TreeMap<String, String> treemap = new TreeMap<String, String>();           
   treemap.put("2", "doi");
   treemap.put("1", "unu");
   treemap.put("3", "trei");
   treemap.put("6", "sase");
   treemap.put("5", "cinci");       

   //Elimina todos los elementos.      
   treemap.clear();

   System.out.println("TreeMap ¿esta vacio?: "+treemap.isEmpty());
```

Se tiene como resultado:

```
TreeMap ¿esta vacio?: true
```

---

El método que usas, [remove()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/treemap_remove.htm) elimina únicamente la asignación para una key dentro del  `TreeMap` (si está presente).

Ejemplo:

```
   TreeMap<String, String> treemap = new TreeMap<String, String>();           
   treemap.put("2", "doi");
   treemap.put("1", "unu");
   treemap.put("3", "trei");
   treemap.put("6", "sase");
   treemap.put("5", "cinci");      
   System.out.println("Remueve valor con key 6: "+treemap.remove("6"));
```

Se tiene como resultado:

```
Remueve valor con key 6: sase
```

---

Este sería un método que usarías, el cual indicaría si se removieron con éxito todos los elementos dentro del TreeMap:

```
public void eliminarProductos(){
     map_catalogo.clear()
}
```

Comment: Hola Elenasys. No quiero ser excesivamente detallista, pero no veo el propósito de ejecutar `map_catalogo.isEmpty()` como si hubiera posibilidad que a veces quede vacío y otras veces no. Si llamas el método `clear()`, el `TreeMap` siempre quedará vacío, por lo que hacer `return true;` daría lo mismo.  Y si vamos a hacer `retrun true;`, mejor cambiar el método para que sea `void`.

Comment: hehe vaya que eres detallista, cuando se limpíe siempre se obtendrá una map vacio. Definí el método como boolean ya que el OP tiene así su método original, aúnque como comentas no necesita obtener el estado ya que sabemos el TreeMap quedaría vacio. Cambio el método a void. Saludos! ☞   ͜ʖ  ☞